# Duplicity SSH error only when run by Cron

Tags: backup, cron, duplicity

I have Duplicity running on my Ubuntu desktop. It runs properly if I run it from the command line, however, when I schedule it with Cron, I get this error:

backendException: ssh connection to userid@server:22 failed: not a valid RSA private key file  (The actual userid and server name were removed)

Running a simple SCP command via Cron to copy a file from my desktop to the backup server runs correctly, so I don't believe SSH is the problem.

Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: Can you post the cronjob so we can see whats happening?

Comment: Are you specifying an identity file directly on the command line, or via a configuration file? is it possible that one expects a key in PEM format and the other in OpenSSH format?

Comment: This issue has cleared up due to some change made last night. Not entirely sure what did it. I suspect a syntax issue in one of the scripts running the backup.  The key file is in PEM format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that an `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env variable is to blame. cron has limited set of variables to set for a process, comparing with a regular Ubuntu environment.

So I had to copy value of it and put the command into the cronfile as:

```
/usr/bin/env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/path/to/socket duplicity ...
```

to make it work.